# Async template in KnockoutJS with owl-carousel

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, owl-carousel

I use a owlCarousel  around knockout data-bound list of custom-components with templates async loaded with require.
In order the setup to work I have to initialize the carousel object after all the DOM elements are rendered. The setTimeout function is a working ugly option. Is there an event of some sort to get notified when knockout completed all its asynchronous DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the afterRender callback of the foreach binding.  Search for "afterRender" on this KO doc page:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

afterRender gets called each time an item in the list is rendered, so you'd probably have to write a little code to do some counting in the viewmodel to know when you've hit your last item in the list, at which time you could then initialize the carousel.  Not super-clean, but certainly better than the setTimeout approach where you'd deal with arbitrary delays and possible race conditions.

Another option would be to write your own custom Knockout binding for the carousel.  Seems like this would be the cleanest approach, and would be reusable.  Looks like there is at least one person who had the same need.  You might find their custom binding on GitHub useful:

https://github.com/Crunc/knockout-owlCarousel

I haven't worked with this binding before so I can't confirm it would fit your needs, but it might be a good starting point for you.